# Using Gitlab CI from a submodule

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, git-submodules

I'm trying to "mutualize" my CI.

I have a lot of project that use basically the same `gitlab-ci.yml`.

I was thinking about creating a git submodule containing the `gitlab-ci.yml` that all my project are using, in which I could inject env variable in order to make it generic so I could re-use it in my futur projects.

My problem is that I don't see any documentation about this so I was wondering :

- Is it possible ? And if yes, how can I tell gitlab to use the `gitlab-ci.yml` that is inside of this submodule ?
- If it's a bad idea, do you have any idea of the correct way to do this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for are Gitlab CI template files, that can be `include`'d in other `.gitlab-ci.yml` files.

You can check out the documentation for `include` [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html).

Example :

```
# .gitlab.ci.yml

include:
  - 'https://gitlab.com/awesome-project/raw/main/.before-script-template.yml'
  - '/templates/.after-script-template.yml'
```

This includes CI files with default variables, stages, workflows that can be overriden anywhere in your other CI files. This brings the genericity you need.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for ! Thanks a lot !